# URL encode in htaccess, maybe?

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

Consider the following scenario:

I want to be able to access `http://www.example.com/word/hello/`, where the word `hello` is variable. So I set up `.htaccess` to configure that.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^word/(.+)/?$ displayword.php?word=$1 [L]
```

I used `.+` because I also want to filter any symbols such as `?+-.!;:` etc.

And I set up my PHP file accordingly:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['word'];
?>
```

Remember that this is just a scenario. Now, I went to this URL: `http://www.example.com/word/Are you ok?/`, and the page outputted this:

```
Are you ok
```

And I couldn't figure out why. But then I realised that the question mark symbol is the starting point of the URL variables.

So is there a way to 'url encode' the question mark in the above example, in order for it to be displayed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to encode it, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^word/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.?]+)/?$ displayword.php?word=$1 [L]
```

It will display `?` in the parameter and any other character you add to the `[group]`. I did not test if the rule works, though, but I suppose it does. Looks ok and that is not the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know heaps about .htaccess files, but you could change your PHP script to use [`$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) instead of `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`.

Particularly, [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#108329) might help you out.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTTP protocol the "?" separates the querystring from the rest of the URL, so I don't think it will be possible to use it directly inside the URL. One solution would be to encode the question mark into `%3F`.

Then you can use [`string urldecode (string $str)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to decode the string.

See this [URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for the encoding of other characters.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+word/([^/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?word=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Reason this works is because RewriteRule works on `%{REQUEST_URI}` which gets URI i.e. string before question mark `?` however `%{THE_REQUEST}` works on the full URL that includes question mark `?` as well.